# Getting "read time out" error while trying to use a Python module

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

While this is 100% Python related, it's not quite an issue with Python itself. The module, called "web3", is used to interact with Ethereum and solidity, yet when I try to send small transaction running on local node, I am getting read-timeout from "HTTP pool" or so.

The error says something about 10 maximum timeout... so maybe if I find/increase 10 to 50 or 100 it will be fixed? Unfortunately there's limited info online and people having the same issue barely manage to solve it with few fixes.

Comment: The error you get you have quoted incorrectly in the title (I bet) and just describe in the body. Please quote literally and fully.

Comment: @sorry, misspelling yes, no idea how to edit the title?

Comment: OK, let's hope this works...:

Comment: >>> from web3 import Web3
        >>> web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545", request_kwargs={'timeout': 60}))

Comment: ^ It seems I can specify the timeout argument here...so I hope that's what I need to increase, got to test it now to confirm.

Comment: Please add information by [edit]ing your question, instead of hiding in comments.

Comment: Are you using geth Javascript REPL or are you creating a python program and running it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using web3.py, the library provides the way to set the timeout.

Set the parameter `websocket_timeout=60` for a  WebsocketProvider:

```py
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider("ws://127.0.0.1:8546", websocket_timeout=60))
```

If you're using HTTP, you set `request_kwargs={'timeout':60}` instead:

```py
from web3 import Web3
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:8545", request_kwargs={'timeout': 60}))
```

Documentation:
https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html